# How to use DbgHelpCreateUserDump?

Tags: c, dbghelp

I wanted to use this function to dump the memory of some processes for analysis, but I didn't find any instructions for this function online.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is part of any public API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the ReactOS source code (`/dll/win32/dbghelp/rosstubs.c`):

```c
BOOL WINAPI
DbgHelpCreateUserDump(LPSTR pszFileName,
                      PDBGHELP_CREATE_USER_DUMP_CALLBACK Callback,
                      PVOID pUserData)
{
    UNIMPLEMENTED;
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL WINAPI
DbgHelpCreateUserDumpW(LPWSTR pszFileName,
                      PDBGHELP_CREATE_USER_DUMP_CALLBACK Callback,
                      PVOID pUserData)
{
    UNIMPLEMENTED;
    return FALSE;
}
```

See also [Microsoft's documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Diagnostics/Debug/fn.DbgHelpCreateUserDump.html); [FreePascal's documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/daily/packages/winunits-jedi/jwawindows/dbghelpcreateuserdump.html).

I haven't found anything more than the function's prototype. It does not look like this is part of the dbghelp public API. Consider [using `MiniDumpWriteDump` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041097/5223757).