Which custom dump flags are used in a WER mini dump?
I'm using Windows Error Reporting's registry settings to capture mini dumps from crashes of my Win32 C++ program.
I want to include string data from my process, at least the string data in scope of the stack trace. However, all string data is excluded when using DumpType 1: Mini dump.
Using the custom dump option and only MINIDUMP_TYPE MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory, the dump captures the desired string data. However, the file is much smaller than the standard mini dump (~400 KB vs. 15 MB) so I worry I'm leaving out crucial information.
Which combination of MINIDUMP_TYPE flags are used in the registry's DumpType 1: Mini dump option?

Depending on needed information, other flags can be used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041097/what-combination-of-minidump-type-enumeration-values-will-give-me-the-most-comp

For a custom dump, you can specify any combination of MINIDUMP_TYPE. The documentation exhaustively explains what these flags do. Whether any given combination is sufficient for your intended use isn't something we can answer for you. You'll have to verify this yourself.

@DanielSęk Yes, I realize this. The info I'm looking for is: What did I exclude by switching from the mini dump option to the custom dump option? I edited my question for clarity.

@IInspectable I am experienced at programming high level languages, but the documentation for many of those options is very low level and beyond my understanding. So I'd like to add MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory to the standard WER mini dump. Any idea which flags the WER mini dump option uses internally? (Edited question for clarity.)

Load mini-dump created with default settings into WinDbg and execute .dumpdebug command. Flags line will tell you which flags were set.

Perhaps Collecting User-Mode Dumps lists default flags:
0x00000121 (MiniDumpWithDataSegs MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData == 0x00000001 0x00000020 0x00000100)
I have created mini-dump with DumpType set to 1 (mini dump).
.dumpdebug command in WinDbg lists following flags for this mini dump:
Flags           00200121
                00000001 MiniDumpWithDataSegs
                00000020 MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules
                00000100 MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData
                00200000 MiniDumpWithAvxXStateContext

I assume that MiniDumpWithAvxXStateContext depends on processor architecture.
